# Error When Compiling C++ File In GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ubuntu

I'm using Linux Ubuntu Intrepid Ibex and using as compiler the *gcc*, but when I try to compile a C++ project file, the compiler give me this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~/C++$ gcc ClientFile.cpp
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have the build suite installed?

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install build-essential
```

and compile C++ code with `g++` command, not `gcc`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your gcc install is damaged, looks like.